# MS Access Queries Not Reflecting Newly Imported Data

Tags: ms-access

What are common reasons for a Query not reflecting newly imported data?

I have a database with three tables with the first linked to the other two.  I have a subdatasheet set up in the first table that are not reflecting newly imported data from the other two tables.  Also Queries that should show all of the data from the tables together are not showing the newly imported data.

I have refreshed the spreadsheets, saved, and close/reopen.  Suggestions?

Comment: Well, if you don't see the data it doesn't sound like it's in your database (not imported)

Comment: Thanks for the comment Mark.  I figured out that the Query that wasn't working was a join between two tables based on ID and Date.  Since some of the imported data included time stamps along with the date and some did not, the join failed and the newly imported data did not reflect in the Query.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Sometimes joins can get bite you if you're not careful.